# search using hotelroomdescription and if its matching show the corresponding hotles and rooms using vuejs / javascript [es5]

Tags: vue.js, ecmascript-5

```
{
  "Data": {
    "Services": [
      {
        "Description": "Test",
        "ServiceID": 147855555,
        "Hotels": [
          {
            "HotelId": "3969f33bc946",
            "HotelName": "Crackle",
            "IsSelected": true,
            "rooms": [
              {
                "RoomId": "0abddf051b2f",
                "HotelRoomDescription": "Room1",
                "IsSelected": false
              },
              {
                "RoomId": "7ea2a918992f",
                "HotelRoomDescription": "Room2",
                "IsSelected": false
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "HotelId": "1c6d71b3dc8a",
            "HotelName": "Steve",
            "IsSelected": true,
            "rooms": [
              {
                "RoomId": "679c9216304f",
                "HotelRoomDescription": "Bar",
                "IsSelected": false
              },
              {
                "RoomId": "b71e7f62c0e9",
                "HotelRoomDescription": "Station",
                "IsSelected": false
              },
              {
                "RoomId": "848abbb3bce7",
                "HotelRoomDescription": "Room 1",
                "IsSelected": false
              },
              {
                "RoomId": "270c22b8ef9e",
                "HotelRoomDescription": "Room 2",
                "IsSelected": false
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "HotelId": "5dfa2733f743",
            "HotelName": "Club",
            "IsSelected": false,
            "rooms": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "Message": "Success",
  "Status": "Success",
  "Type": 0
}
```

In front end side, I have shown the details as tree. For example, if we search 'bar', then hotel name 'Steve' contains the  room 'bar'. then need to show the corresponding hotel name and HotelRoomDescription. If we didn't search, it list the entire hotel names and their corresponding room as tree structure.

Here `roomSearch` is the v-model, whatever we typed for searching, getting the value through this.

```js
if(this.roomSearch.trim() === "") return this.hotels;

var roomenames = this.hotels.filter(function(hotel){
  return hotel.HotelRoomDescription.toLowerCase().indexOf(_this.roomSearch.toLowerCase()) -1;
});
return roomenames;
```

The code which is written inside have mistakes, its not filter the `HotelRoomDescription`. Its not going inside rooms.....

Answer (score 0):

You try to filter the HotelRoomDescription on a hotel (`hotel.HotelRoomDescription`) but, according to your data, the "HotelRoomDescription" is a "room" property.

In your filter function, you need to loop a second time over the `hotel.rooms`.
Here's an example that works (with simplified data, surely needs to be improved):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data () {
    return {
      hotels: [
        {
          "HotelName": "Crackle",
          "rooms": [
            { "HotelRoomDescription": "Room1" },
            { "HotelRoomDescription": "Room2" }
          ]
        },
        {
          "HotelName": "Steve",
          "rooms": [
            { "HotelRoomDescription": "Bar" },
            { "HotelRoomDescription": "Station" },
            { "HotelRoomDescription": "Room 1" },
            { "HotelRoomDescription": "Room 2" }
          ]
        },
        {
          "HotelName": "Club",
          "rooms": []
        }
      ],
      roomSearch: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredHotels () {
      var self = this
      if (this.roomSearch.trim() === '') return this.hotels
      return this.hotels.filter(function(h) {
       return h.rooms.some(function(r) {
          return r.HotelRoomDescription.toLowerCase().includes(self.roomSearch.toLowerCase())
        })
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    filteredRooms(rooms) {
      var self = this
      if (this.roomSearch.trim() === '') return rooms
      return rooms.filter(function(r) {
       return r.HotelRoomDescription.toLowerCase().includes(self.roomSearch.toLowerCase())
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="roomSearch">
  <ol>
    <li v-for="hotel in filteredHotels">
    <h4>{{ hotel.HotelName }}</h4>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="room in filteredRooms(hotel.rooms)">
          {{ room.HotelRoomDescription }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```